# How do I get R to read out morphological data contained on .tps files?

Tags: r, file, morphological-analysis, tps

I have 7 images of flowers that I have used the digitize2d function in the geomorph package to measure the nectar tube length data. While the function works and R tells me that "All specimens from the session have been digitized to the .tps file" I can't find a way to get R to read out the data contained in those files, that I would then like to add to a larger excel sheet of functional trait data. How can I can get those numbers out of the tps file? My function that generate the .tps file looks like:

```
library(geomorph)

#Locate image to digitize the distance between two points
digitize2d("Capnoides.jpg", nlandmarks = 2, scale = 1, "Capnoides.tps", 
verbose=TRUE)
```

In the question thread ["Reading a .tps file into R"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729491/reading-a-tps-morphometrics-file-into-r) someone generated a code to read out a .tps file but when I try to run it I get the error message "Error in read.table(file = data, header = F, skip = ID.ind[i], nrows = 1,  : 
  no lines available in input"

Thank you!

Comment: doesn't `geomorph` have `readland.tps`?

Comment: yep. it does and `readland.tps("Capnoides.tps")` worked for me.